# Unable to create a list of properties for each node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two files. First file contain list of users with certain properties. I have loaded them in Neo4j as below:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///users.csv" AS row
CREATE (U:User{userid:row.userid, username:row.username})
```

Now, I have a second file that contains pincodes of the places the user stays or ever stayed at. Example:
User Pincodes

```
A 001

B 002

A 003
```

I want to add a property to the label User such that it adds all the pincodes as a list. But when I am using the below query, it only stores the most latest value and not all the values as a list.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///user_pincode.csv" AS line
MATCH (U:User)
WHERE U.userid=line.userid 
SET U.pincode=[line.pincode]
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

You can do this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///user_pincode.csv" AS line
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.userid=line[0]
SET u.pincode = COALESCE(u.pincode, []) + line[1]
```

Since your CSV data has no header, this query omits the `WITH HEADERS` option, and treats `line` as an array. It appends the new pincode to the end of the existing `pincode` list (or, if the `pincode` property did not already exist, initialize that property with a single-element list). The `COALESCE` function returns the first argument that is non-NULL.

Comment: This query is not adding the pincodes to the property correctly.